# Openshift site shuts down unexpectedly

Tags: openshift

I have a site hosted on OpenShift. Every so often, maybe once every two weeks, the server appears to randomly shut down the site. I get a 503 error on the page and the server log says:

```
DEBUG: Sending SIGTERM to child...
Thu Aug 06 2015 11:27:21 GMT-0400 (EDT): Received SIGTERM - terminating sample app ...
Thu Aug 06 2015 11:27:21 GMT-0400 (EDT): Node server stopped.
==> app-root/logs/mongodb.log <==
Thu Aug  6 11:27:19.208 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Thu Aug  6 11:27:19.208 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Thu Aug  6 11:27:19.208 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Thu Aug  6 11:27:19.208 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: final commit...
Thu Aug  6 11:27:19.212 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: closing all files...
Thu Aug  6 11:27:19.213 [signalProcessingThread] closeAllFiles() finished
Thu Aug  6 11:27:19.215 [signalProcessingThread] journalCleanup...
Thu Aug  6 11:27:19.215 [signalProcessingThread] removeJournalFiles
Thu Aug  6 11:27:19.269 [signalProcessingThread] shutdown: removing fs lock...
Thu Aug  6 11:27:19.314 dbexit: really exiting now
```

I can restart the app and it works fine again for a while but I would prefer to find the source of the issue and solve it.  The error doesn't mean much to me. Where should I start looking for the origin of the SIGTERM?